# Добавление в словарь списка без скобок

Tags: python, python-3.x, xmlparser

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу добавить в словарь ссылки на картинки без [], чтобы в дальнейшем загрузить все товары с картинками на сайт

Вот сам код:

```
import requests
#import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

HOST = "САЙТ"
CSV = 'parsing.csv'
def get_html(url): #берём html стрраницы, которую будем парсить
    r= requests.get(url)
    return r
def get_url_site(url_category): #Получаем линки сайд бара
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_category, 'html.parser')
    categorys = soup.find_all('dt')
    urls = []
    for item in categorys:
        if item.find('a').get('href') == None:
            continue
        else:
            urls.append(HOST + item.find('a').get('href'))
    return urls
def get_url_tovar(url_tovar): # Получаем линки товара настранице
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_tovar, 'html.parser')
    tovar = soup.find_all('h4', class_='item-title')
    urls = []
    for item in tovar:
        if item.find('a').get('href') == None:
            continue
        else:
            urls.append(HOST + item.find('a').get('href'))
    return urls
def get_pagination(url_tovar_pagin): # получаем количество страниц
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_tovar_pagin, 'html.parser')
    PAGINATION = soup.find('div', class_='pagination')
    if PAGINATION == None:
        pass
    else:
        PAGINATION = soup.find('div', class_='pagination').find_all(string=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19'])
        for item in PAGINATION:
            if item.find('a') == None:
                continue
            else:
                
                return PAGINATION

def get_all_tovar(): # получаем линк со всех товаров сайта
    URL_sidebar = get_url_site(get_html(HOST).text)
    tovar_url = []
    for i in range(1): #len(URL_sidebar)
        URL_tovar = get_url_tovar(get_html(URL_sidebar[i]).text)
        num_pagination = get_pagination(get_html(URL_sidebar[i]).text)
        if num_pagination != None:
            for item_pagination in range(len(num_pagination)):
                URL_tovar_1 = get_html(URL_sidebar[i]+"/"+num_pagination[item_pagination])
                for b in range (len(get_url_tovar(URL_tovar_1.text))):
                    tovar_url.append(get_url_tovar(URL_tovar_1.text)[b])
        else:
            for c in range (len(URL_tovar)):
                tovar_url.append(URL_tovar[c])
    return tovar_url
        #print (URL_tovar, num_pagination)
get_all_tovar()

def save_doc(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['название', 'цена', 'картинка', 'Описание'])#заголовки
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow( [item['title'], item['price'], item['img'], item['text']])#заголовки         
            
def parss():    
    tovar = []
    for a in range(len(get_all_tovar())):
        connect = get_html(get_all_tovar()[a]).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(connect, 'html.parser')
        tovar_pars = soup.find_all('div', class_='jbzoo')
        tovar_link = []
        for b in tovar_pars:
            if b.find('h2', class_='element-itemname') == None:
                continue
            else:
                for link in b.find('div', class_='rborder').find_all('a', class_='jbimage-link'):
                    tovar_link.append (HOST+link.get('href'))
                
                tovar.append(
                    {
                        'title':b.find('h2', class_='element-itemname').get_text(),
                        'price':b.find('span', class_='price-value').get_text(),
                        'img':tovar_link,
                        'text':b.find('div', class_='element-textarea').get_text(strip=True),
                    }
                )
            
        save_doc(tovar,CSV)
        print(tovar, len(tovar))
    
parss()
```

Вывод:

```
[{'title': ' ', 'img': ['/images/brands/baikal/1baikal.jpg', '/images/brands/baikal/2baikal.jpg', '/images/brands/baikal/3baikal', '/images/brands/baikal/4baikal', '/images/brands/baikal/5baikal', '/images/brands/baikal/6baikal'], 'text': ''}]
```

Какой вывод необходим

```
[{'title': ' ', 'img': '/images/brands/baikal/1baikal.jpg', '/images/brands/baikal/2baikal.jpg', '/images/brands/baikal/3baikal.jpg', '/images/brands/baikal/4baikal.jpg', '/images/brands/baikal/5baikal.jpg', '/images/brands/baikal/6baikal.jpg', 'text': ''}]
```

Comment: Необходимый вывод синтаксически неправильный. Вы его потом как хотите использовать?

Comment: @Jazzis мне нужно в дальнейшем скормить данный файл в Woocomerce, чтобы он добавил товары с картинками, которые будут указаны в файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам получается надо просто избавиться от квадратных скобок выводимого списка. Перепишите метод `save_doc` следующим образом:

```py
def save_doc(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['название', 'цена', 'картинка', 'Описание'])#заголовки
        for item in items:
            # если список пуст, то ничего не выводим в столбец
            images = ''
            # иначе выводим без квадратных скобок
            if len(item['img']) > 0:
                images = str(item['img'])[1:-1]
            writer.writerow( [item['title'], item['price'], images, item['text']])#заголовки
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ, а также за то, что смогли разобрать мой код. Действительно, существуют такие методы как срезы, про которые я забыл. Не занимался питоном в течение 4 лет, остановился на уровне классов. Вот спустя длительное время необходимо было решить свою тревиальную бизнес-задачу, бьюсь 2-ой день =) Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь!!!